# Allow VOIP iOS app to recieve calls whilst app is resigned to background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to iOS development and currently working on a VOIP app. I'm currently trying to allow the app to receive calls through the app while it has been resigned to the background.

Unfortunately I cannot share code as this is a project at work. So would really appreciate it if anyone could maybe point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from "https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html"

> To configure a VoIP app, you must do the following:
>
> Enable support for Voice over IP from the Background modes section of the Capabilities tab in your Xcode project. (You can also enable this support by including the UIBackgroundModes key with the VoIP value in your app’s Info.plist file.)

1. Configure one of the app’s sockets for VoIP usage.
2. Before moving to the background, call the setKeepAliveTimeout:handler: method  to install a handler to be executed periodically. Your app can use this handler to maintain its service connection.
3. Configure your audio session to handle transitions to and from active use.

This page may also be useful:-  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW13

Comment: Hey thanks for the link coming in really handy. Having trouble configuring sockets but il keep at it

Answer (score 1):

Select App target 
   In Info list add Required background modes
  Add App provides Voice over IP services

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had already done that in the info list.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project settings, select `Capabilities` under `target` selected. Select `background mode` and turn on switch beside it. so, you will get many option from that `check Voice Over IP`. That's it. It will add key to your `info.plist`. Refer below screenshot,

[image]

Second thing you can directly add keys in `info.plist` as `RequiredBackgrounModes` also!

Refer [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html) to know how to implement and manage it.

Comment: Thanks,i had this already set up,including the the info list.

Answer (score 0):

the link below shows a detailed step by step on setting this up.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios